# Cannot access to my webcam opencv ubuntu

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu, webcam

here is my code

```
#include <iostream>

#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

using namespace std;

const int KEY_ENTER = 10;
const int KEY_ESC   = 27;
const int KEY_1         = 49;
const int KEY_2         = 50;
const int KEY_3         = 51;
const int KEY_4         = 52;
const int KEY_5         = 53;
const int KEY_6         = 54;

const int DELAY = 30;

const string WIN_NAME = "Camera View";

const string NAME[6] = {"me", "serk", "prot", "vitkt", "st", "tara"};

struct pg
{
string name;
int cnt;
pg(): name(""), cnt (0) {};
pg(string s, int c) : name(s) , cnt(c) {};
};

pg crew[6];

int main()
{
for(int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
    crew[i] = pg(NAME[i], 0);

cv::VideoCapture cam;

cam.open(0);

cv::Mat frame;

pg cur = crew[0];

int c = 0;
for(;cam.isOpened();)
{
    try
    {
    cam >> frame;

    cv::imshow(WIN_NAME, frame);

    int key = cv::waitKey(DELAY);

    cur = (key >= KEY_1 && key <= KEY_6) ? crew[key - KEY_1] : cur;

    if(KEY_ENTER == key)
        cv::imwrite(cv::format("%s%d.jpg", cur.name.c_str(), cur.cnt++), frame);

    if(KEY_ESC == key)
        break;
    } catch (cv::Exception e)
    {
        cout << e.err << endl;
    }
}

cam.release();
return 0;
}
```

but I cannot capture a video from camera. =( 
I've got Ubuntu 12.04 on my PC,

I did exactly every instruction in [linux install istructions](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html) 
I googled my problem and installed additional dependencies 
this

- python-opencv
- libhighgui2.3
- libhighgui-dev
- ffmpeg
- libgstreamer0.10-0
- libv4l-0
- libv4l-dev
- libxine2
- libunicap2
- libdc1394-22

and many others which I can find. 
but it still doesn't work.
It's ridiculous but this code works on my laptop, with the same distribution of ubuntu.
I have no compilation errors.

in terminal
    gstreamer-properties 
opens that camera. 
Does someone know what to do? Help me please.

I've noticed that it even doesn't load pictures from file

code example 
    #include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
    #include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
system("clear");

cv::Mat picture;
picture = cv::imread("boobies.jpg");

cout << picture.rows << endl;
cv::imshow("Smile", picture);

char ch;
cin >> ch;

cv::destroyWindow("Smile");

return 0;
}
```

haven't load the picture from project folder

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to initilize `cam`. you must use the constructor with `int` as parameter.

```
// the constructor that opens video file
VideoCapture(const string& filename);
// the constructor that starts streaming from the camera
VideoCapture(int device);
```

Do it like:

```
cv::VideoCapture cam(0);
cam.open(0);
```

Also, you could use `cvCaptureFromCAM`:

```
CvCapture *capture;
capture = cvCaptureFromCAM( 0 );
```

This will allocates and initializes your capture instance.

Comment: hmm, but I did it always without initialization and it worked,

Comment: I use VideoCapture cam(0)
or cam.open(0)

I think it works same ways.

Actually I think the problem with Linux distribution, because I can normally build it yesterday, and the next day linker cannot find the libraries. =(

I'll try to reinstall it.

Comment: what do you get as error? since it isn't working, what did you changed? did you tried it? did you tried the cvCaptureFromCAM. maybe opencv changed something and your current version don't accept it... wich version has opencv?

Comment: opencv 2.4.6, yes I did try. nothing is changed. I think the problem is with highgui lib. Also It is seemed to be with putting the picture on the form(or window). Properties of the picture is avaliable after loading, like rows or columns amount. I think the problem with cv::imshow() function.

Comment: If i got something as an error. I'd google first =) but there is no any errors. I tried \try catch\ block but it doesn't throw any exception. videocapture doesn't open camera and picture isn't show in window. Yes I did check the name of the file =) it is correct

Answer (score 1):

if you are under Opencv 2.4.6 it has been hotfixed: http://opencv.org/hot-fix-for-opencv-2-4-6.html